# C# Visual Studio : how can I differentiate database per users

Tags: c#, local-database

I am writing a grading system using Visual Studio 2010 C# using a local database and I am just going to ask on how can I do a log in form for every users that shows a data in a combo box or data grid view that is assign to them during run time.

Where other users can't see all the data in database, they can only see the data that is assign to them during run time. I tried making it by assigning a user id per subject but it didn't work hope you can help me thank you :)

```
if (scmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString() == "1")  
{  
    pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\Mic 18\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\mylogin\granted.png");  
    MessageBox.Show("YOU ARE GRANTED WITH ACCESS");  
}    
else  
{           
    pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\Mic 18\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\mylogin\denied.jpg");  
    MessageBox.Show("YOU ARE NOT GRANTED WITH ACCESS");  

    lbl_Msg.Text = ("You have only " + Convert.ToString(attempt) + " attempts left to try");  

     --attempt;  
     txt_UserName.Clear();  
     txt_PWD.Clear();  
 }
```

I am trying using this code but it only do a user level

Answer (score 0):

You have a `ConnectionClass` isnt it?, some class with this:

```cs
        public SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        public SqlDataAdapter sda;
        public SqlDataReader sdr;
        public DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        public SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conStr"].ToString());
```

Then the signIn method:

```cs
protected void btnSignIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string Query = "select * from table where Email='" + txtEmail.Value + "' and Password='" + txtPassword.Value + "'";
            if (ConnC.IsExist(Query))
            {
                string UserName = ConnC.GetColumnVal(Query, "UserName");
                Session["UserName"] = UserName;
                Session["Email"] = txtEmail.Value;
                Response.Redirect("someaspxpage.aspx");
            }
            else
                txtEmail.Value = "Invalid Email or Password!!";
        }
```

Where your IsExist() returns `true` if(hasRows):

```cs
public bool IsExist(string Query)
        {
            bool check = false;
            using (cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, con))
            {
                con.Open();
                sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (sdr.HasRows)
                    check = true;
            }
            sdr.Close();
            con.Close();
            return check;

        }
```